# Regular expression to capture only words in a tagged corpus

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing some experiment with NLP in Python. I know about NLTK, but right now I'm not using it. I have a tagged corpus and I want to capture the words only, not their tags through regular expression.

For example,
    `\n\n\tthe/at fulton/np-tl county/nn-tl grand/jj-tl jury/nn-tl said/vbd` is a portion of the tagged corpus and I want to extract the words. I'm new in using `re` module. Please suggest some pattern so that it can be helpful to my work.

Comment: wait, what are their tags? The /np-tl /nn-tl stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@maxymoo's answer is correct for the example you posted, but will not work if some words in your corpus contain slashes (e.g., "and/or"), or hyphens.

To capture hyphenated words, replace `(\w+)` in his answer with `(\w+-\w+|\w+)`.

Slashes are more difficult. You need to gather a full list of tags and write a look-ahead.

Comment: thanks gill....but you can also use `r'([\w-]+)/'` (equivalent to your suggestion) also. Let me know your view.

Comment: `[\w-]+` is more permissive. It matches '--', '---', '-ing', '2016-02-10' etc, while `\w+-\w|\w` will not. Well maybe those don't occur in your corpus, in which case the two versions indeed do the same thing (and yours is shorter). But if those do occur and you want to exclude them, then you need the sandwich version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to match a word followed by a slash, but not including the slash, the regex for this would be `(\w+)/`, -- the brackets tell you which group you want to keep -- or in python

```
re.findall('(\w+)/',s)
```